# Java - Removing an Unnecessary (maybe) Type Parameter

Tags: java, generics

I have a class `AbstractConstraint` like

```
public abstract class AbstractConstraint<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    // ...
}
```

and several concrete classes such as

```
public class IntegerConstraint extends AbstractConstraint<Integer> {
    // Integer extends Comparable<Integer>
}
```

This is well and good, but becomes very unwieldy when I specify an `AbstractConstraint` as a type parameter. For example:

```
public class ConstraintCollection<C extends AbstractConstraint<T>, T extends Comparable<T>> {
    // Implementation that relies on T being Comparable
}
```

To get an instance of `ConstraintColleciton` I do

```
ConstraintCollection<IntegerConstraint, Integer> foor = new ConstraintCollection<>();
```

Having to specify `Integer` as a type parameter here seems unnecessary, it seems to me that it is implied by `IntegerConstraint`. The example here is somewhat trivial (I could just use a wildcard) but carrying this further just leads to insanity and code that is best described as 'write only.'

Is there a way to for me to define `ConstraintCollection` so that it requires only one type parameter (or make any other changes to the same effect)?

Comment: Can you add a compilable example? It's hard to answer without knowing how the type parameters are used.

Comment: if `AbstractConstraint` uses/encapsulates the generic type `<T extends Comparable<T>>`, in the `ConstraintCollection` do you really need 2 generic arguments? would `AbstractConstraint<T>` be enough? in other words, can you discard `T extends Comparable<T>` from that declaration? If you manage to do this, `ConstraintCollection<IntegerConstraint>` will be enough.

Comment: why not to define your `ConstraintCollection` as `ConstraintCollection<C extends AbstractConstraint<?>>`? 

As the `AbstractConstraint` already has bound constraints applied to its T